# Do I need a Canada transit visa as an Indian citizen?

Tags: visas, air-travel, transit, canada, indian-citizens

I am travelling from US to Bangalore (INDIA) via Canada, in Canada I have to change the flight from Air Canada to Ethihad airways and have layover time of 3 hours. I'm an Indian citizen. Do I need a Canada transit visa? I don't want to visit Canada.

Comment: What's your citizenship?

Comment: It amazes me how many people ask similar questions without thinking that their own nationality is really important for a correct answer.

Comment: Depends if you will have to do a check-in again in Canada, in short - clear the immigration.

Comment: I appologize for not mentioning earlier. I am an Indian citizen.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need a visa to transit Canada.

See: http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp?country=India

Getting a transit visa is fairly simple. You can use this tool to apply.
http://onlineservices-servicesenligne.cic.gc.ca/eapp/eapp.do